# jQuery ajax post to web service

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, web-services, ashx

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                        url: "/getprojects.ashx",
                        data: "<formData client=\"\" year=\"\" categories=\"\" tags=\"\" freeText=\"\" count=\"34\" page=\"1\"></formData>",
                        dataType: "text/xml",
                        cache: false,
                        error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
                        success: function(xml) {
                            alert("it works");
                            alert($(xml).find("project")[0].attr("id"));
                        }
        });
    });
```

My problem is i get some data back but i can't seem to get it displayed.

Comment: How does this data look like? What part of it do you want to extract? How and where do you want it formated and displayed?

Comment: The data i get looks like this:
<content>
<outcome success="1" requestId="" command="" />
<projects totalNumberOfProjects="226" selectedNofProjects="34" curPage="1" nOfPages="7">
<project id="378" title="Campaign" confidential="1" client="Client1" image="" thumb="" publicLink="" internalLink="" />
</projects>
</content>
I some of the attributes on all the projects, displayed in html.

Comment: if you used alternating single quotes/double quotes you wouldn't need to escape them all :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dataType` should be the type of what you receive but `contentType` should be the mime-type of what you are sending, the following should be ok:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                        url: "/getprojects.ashx",
                        data: "<formData client=\"\" year=\"\" categories=\"\" tags=\"\" freeText=\"\" count=\"34\" page=\"1\"></formData>",
                        contentType: "text/xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        cache: false,
                        error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
                        success: function(xml) {
                            alert("it works");
                            alert($(xml).find("project")[0].attr("id"));
                        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: the error callback signature is error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) what are the values of the parameters?

Comment: [object XMLHttpRequest parsererror TypeError: a is null] but ive kinda given up and move on but an answer on how to get it working would still be appreciated.

Comment: The question now is whether the issue is while sending or receiving data. Do your server receive the request and what is its response?

Comment: For this, can you please show me any sample WebMethod?

Answer (score 2):

Your `dataType` seems to be wrong. It should look like

```
dataType: "xml"
```

Your `data` structure also looks pretty wierd. Have a look at [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). It should be standard query string **foo=bar&test=bla** etc.

If the `success handler` gets executed, try to lookup your `xml` variable plain, without
operating on it with `.find()` or whatever. Still empty?

Comment: @Buckley: see my post again, your `data` is also incorrect. If it still executes the error handler, lookup the error code/string by passing `function(xhr, textStatus, error)`

Comment: Thanks jAndy, im having a bit of trouble with the .serializeArray()

Comment: I get a [object XMLHttpRequest parsererror TypeError: a is null] with function(xhr, textStatus, error)