# JQuery Ajax POST XML structure / Filter Chain

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I want to Post an XML structure via AJAX to get a filtered result set. The webservice is able to handle post requests, but something seems to be wrong with my POSTing.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        inputxml: escape('<test></test>') <- how to post xml structure correctly?
    }, 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "text",
    success : parse,
    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
        alert(xhr.status);          
        alert(thrownError);
    } 
});
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:filterChain
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:f="urn:foo">
    <f:filter attributeId="number">
        <f:rangeCondition conditionSign="INCLUSION" operator="BETWEEN">
            <f:low>5</f:low>
            <f:high>15</f:high>
        </f:rangeCondition>
    </f:filter>
</f:filterChain>
```

Thanks

Comment: and you are receiving xml response?

Comment: have you tried the answer? do you get any errors?

Comment: yeah getting still the http 500 error, internal server error, i'll add the xml trying to post.. wait for edit. thanks (now :))

Comment: you will have to escape the quotes etc see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/3099369/413670, also try sending a simple xml like `"<test></test>"` se if it gets posted

Comment: my result is still empty but the ajax post is working and running into the success function... thats a good step. thanks, anything else to take care of? like mime-type or something?

Comment: if your result is empty then i means the server is not sending the correct response, check in the firebug if you are getting any response if yes then you need to post code for the `parse` function that you have supplied as the success callback

Comment: its working :) thanks, could you edit your comment below with the link you've posted with the escaping? then I could accept it as an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: "<test></test>", 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "text",
    success : parse,
    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
        console.log(xhr.status);          
        console.log(thrownError);
    } 
});
```

see this SO answer it may help

[jQuery ajax post to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099369/jquery-ajax-post-to-web-service)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's best to set your values in an object and send that object over to the server as xml by setting the dataType of the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to 'xml'.

Comment: Just create an object that you send as data like { 'test' : 'test' }

Comment: will jquery automatically convert an object to xml, if you set the data as xml?