# Using $.ajax to POST XML to MVC Controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a simple controller function like this:

```
<HttpPost>
Function SaveXML(payload As String) As Boolean
    If payload IsNot Nothing AndAlso payload.Length > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Which I'm calling from JavaScript like this:

```
function SaveXML() {

    var payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data>XML_GOES_HERE</data>';

    // Calls controller correctly but data is null
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Data/SaveXML/",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text/xml",
        data: payload
    })
    .done(function () { alert('Application saved.'); })
    .fail(function () { alert('Application failed to save.'); });

}
```

I'm using the example on the [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as a base with some advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099369/jquery-ajax-post-to-web-service), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345107/jquery-ajax-post-xml-structure-filter-chain), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099369/jquery-ajax-post-to-web-service). I've tried it with and without `processData: false` and it makes no difference.

When the call comes in to the Controller method the payload is `null`. [If I post a simple string using some very similar code everything works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976402/using-ajax-or-post-to-call-mvc-5-controller-method). What precisely needs to be done in order to post XML to a Controller via `$.ajax`? Is it at the JavaScript or Controller end that the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to find some hints on this and ended up with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Data/SaveXML/",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ payload: payload })
})
.done(function () { alert('Application saved.'); })
.fail(function () { alert('Application failed to save.'); });
```

The crucial differences are that the `contentType` is set to `application/json`, the data is turned into an object which is then run through the `JSON.stringify` method to make sure that the various characters that are unsuitable for a `querystring` can be sent without failing.

Answer (score 1):

The default model binding doesn't work with processData set to false. If ServerXml is a string of XML, removing this should make it work:

```
function SendXmlToServer(ServerXml) {
   $.ajax({ url: "/Home/XmlData",
       type: "POST",
       data: { ResXml: ServerXml }, dataType: "xml",
       success: function () {
           alert("Successful");
           return false;
       }
   });
}
```

You'll also have to add the ValidateInput attribute to your action method, because normally "HTML markup" isn't allowed:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult XmlData(string ResXml) 
{   
    return null;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use custom model binding to seamlessly deserialize the XML, as explained in this blog post url https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/24/model-binding-xml-in-asp-net-mvc-3/.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to name the parameter you are passing to the controller.

So, something like...

```
var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data>XML_GOES_HERE</data>';

$.ajax({
    url: "/Data/SaveXML/",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    data: { payload: data }
})
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, [in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976402/using-ajax-or-post-to-call-mvc-5-controller-method), this appears to have been answered, and solved?

Comment: If you check again there's a distinct difference between that and this even though they use very similar JavaScript. Here I'm asking how to send XML whereas the other question only sends a simple string.