# generate a file using jquery and pass it to php

Tags: javascript, php

everyone, I am making a website. It can generate a MS excel file using jquery and download. The question is that I hope this generated file can be sent as an attachment in an email using php, so firstly how can I pass the generated file to php?

The following simplified code illustrates my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#excelExport").click(function() {

    var fileexample;//file declaration before generation

    ....//generate the file

    fileexample.click();//download the file

    return fileexample;
});});
```

I have tried some methods to solve the problem as the following, just a reference:

1. pass the fileexample variable using jquery ajax POST request to php server, but it cannot work. It can only work when passing normal variable like a string.
2. put the javascript code and php code together in a php file. But I don't how to call the javascript fileexample variable in php code.
3. put the javascript code and php code together in a php file and use php to generate a MS excel file. But how to call the javascript normal variable like document.getElementById("XXX") in php code.

Hope someone can help me, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So the file is a data uri?

Comment: The code here does almost nothing, and what it does do won't do what you say it will. What exactly do you want from us?

Comment: @Musa the file is not a data uri. The code created a temp HTML link element, store the data and generate it as a MS excel file

Comment: @MikeW Sorry about my poor Engish, the code here can generate a excel file and download, I am wondering if I can pass that file to php. Also, I have tried some methods above, maybe other alternative choice can solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Judging from the title a library that does it, found from google, could be

http://excelbuilderjs.com/

As it is nicely explained on the first page the main reason to do that would be to avoid contacting the server. Otherwise there is no good reason to create an excel on the client and then send it to your server.

Regarding your methods,

1.You can post xml data created at the client from js to the server [jQuery ajax post to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099369/jquery-ajax-post-to-web-service)

2.It is not possible to call js code in php. Javascript is executed at client side, php at server side. You can merely prepare the js that will be executed at client side, within your php code at server side.

3.This is probably towards the right direction. Prepare the xls file with php at server side and providing it as a result to php call by having visited a page or a js call via ajax. Then you could allow the download of your file from the resulting php page, or via js as a response to the ajax call.

Comment: thx, I am trying to solve the problem by your idea

Comment: also a very nice article, a bit old but gives good directions  https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/

Comment: I solve the problem by passing the raw data to php side and generate file at the server side, thx again