# XML sent using ajax POST not being received server side (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, laravel-5

Im trying to send XML using a an ajax POST request but no data is being received server side.

Im using jQuery to send the data:

```
<script>
    $('.buttonXML').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test142"
            , type: "POST"
            , contentType: "text/xml"
            , processData: false
            , data: {xml: '<test></test>'}
            , success: function(){
                console.log('done');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

No data is received by my php:

```
public function post()
{
    DD(Input::get('xml'));
}
```

This outputs 'null'

```
public function post()
{
    DD(Input::all());
}
```

This outputs an empty array

can anyone see what i am missing.

I have disabled Csrf protection for the purposes of testing.

Comment: What is the output of `DD($_POST);`?

Comment: just tested and it outputs an empty array []

Comment: Check the Network tab in your developer tools and ensure that the data was sent

Comment: You can also try seeing if it was sent as a raw POST (i.e. not in a variable, but as an XML POST). `DD(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: Thanks so much ^^ did the trick! I accidently removed my upvote and it wont let me redo :(

Comment: No problem... I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that it's being POSTed as a RAW XML POST, so Laravel isn't picking it up (neither is `$_POST` for that matter). Use this to get at the RAW POST.

```
$xml = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send data as XML string, and dump $_POST variable to see if something happens.

```
data: {xml: '<test></test>'}
```

change:

```
data: '<test></test>'
```

**UPDATED**

found useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3099668/4015178

Comment: I did this and this also returns an empty array