# Adding Accept header 'text/xml' in JQuery ajax file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I add an accept header 'text/xml' in JQuery ajax file upload?
It will upload a PDF file.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('file'));
$.ajax({
  url: '/myurlhere',
  type: 'POST',
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('success... '+response);
  }
}).fail(function(xhr,status,error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The server expects the accept header to be xml, so causes a 406 error.
I have tried using dataType: 'xml' or header { Accept: 'text/xml' } and it causes a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `contentType` to `"text/xml"`.

Change your call like this:

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('file'));
$.ajax({
  url: '/myurlhere',
  type: 'POST',
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "text",
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('success... '+response);
  }
}).fail(function(xhr,status,error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

see this SO answer it may help

[jQuery ajax post to web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099369/jquery-ajax-post-to-web-service)

Comment: Hi, I have tried contentTYpe: 'text/xml' and dataType: 'text', but I am getting a 406 Not Acceptable error and I checked the developer tools and it shows the Accept header as text/plain, which is probably why it is not working because the server accepts text/xml. I tried dataType: 'xml' and I get 400 error. Any other ideas?